# Grep out 'most' of the lines that meet a certain conditon

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have 16 million line data file that I am using as part of a regression testing/replay tool.  The data has a lot of similar lines.  I would like to remove many of those similar lines from the files

File is in format

```
|DATA|DATA|DATE|3|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|3|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|3|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|2|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|4|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|2|DATA|DATA
|DATA|DATA|DATE|2|DATA|DATA
```

The file is 16 million lines and the lines with the 4th element of 2, 3, or 10 make up 13 million lines.  The lines with 4th element of 2, 3 or 10 are all similar to each other so I would like to prune 90% of them from the file.   To get some counts of message type I was able to  run this command to find all the lines with a 4th element of 3

```
awk -F"|" '$4=="3"' capture.txt > out.txt
```

That line was what I used to determine how repeatable the most common messages are but it does nothing to help me prune those records.  What I really want is to be able to create a new file that includes

```
    (All records where pipe deliminated 4th element is not 2, 3 or 10) +
    (1 out of every 10 records where the 4th element is 2, 3 or 10)
```

Is that possible in one pass through the file?  I figured I could create two files, separating out the records with a 4th element of 2, 3 or 10 from those that had a different 4th element.   I could then likely drop every 10th line from the one file and cat them back together.  But my real preference is to do this in one pass and retain the original file order.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In your sample input, it looks like you actually care about $5, not $4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a randomized approach will be better.

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{srand()} $5~/^(2|3|10)$/{if(rand()<0.1) print; next}1' file
```

will be around 10% chance of printing those lines,  you can set a seed to make it repeatable as well.  Note that you should be checking fifth field, not fourth.

Comment: That's both a better idea and a cleaner implementation than my poor attempt.  I'll go back to work now.

Answer (score 0):

The sample input you provide has the constant string "DATE" in $4, but $5 has 2,3, and 4, so you are probably looking for something like:

```
awk '$5 != 2 && $5 != 3 && $5 != 10 {print; next} a++%10 == 0' FS=\| input > output
```